Format of Matrix, and Proof of Interesting derivative property
How can I simplify this matrix (remove some of the dots and coefficients) while maintaining clarity and amount of information for the reader? Additionally, how can I prove this equality? I derived this by intuition upon completing a problem for my calculus homework, $ \frac{d}{dx} \frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, where I discovered the solution, $\frac{ad-bc}{(cx+d)^2}$, had a numerator equal to the determinant of a general 2x2 matrix, and decided to generalize it for higher-order polynomials of degree $2^{2k-1}-1$. I have little to no experience with mathematics beyond pre-calculus, however, any proof would be greatly appreciated.

Let $$A=\left|\begin{array}{cccc}a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_{2^k-1}\\a_{2^k} & a_{2^k+1} & \cdots &a_{2^{k+1}-1}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    a_{\frac{4^k}{2}-2^k} & a_{\frac{4^k}{2}-2^k+1} & \cdots & a_{\frac{4^k}{2}-1}\\
    b_0 & b_1 & \cdots & b_{2^k-1}\\
    b_{2^k} & b_{2^k+1} & \cdots &b_{2^{k+1}-1}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    b_{\frac{4^k}{2}-2^k} & b_{\frac{4^k}{2}-2^k+1} & \cdots & b_{\frac{4^k}{2}-1}\\
    \end{array}
    \right|$$
Let
$$ P(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2^{2k-1}-1}a_nx^n, \;Q(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2^{2k-1}-1}b_nx^n,\;
f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$$ If $k\in\mathbb{N},$ does $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{A}{Q(x)}$?


This is a very interesting idea!  I think it may not be true as written, because if any row is equal to zero --- which will happen for some polynomials --- the entire determinant is equal to zero, even though the derivative of f is not zero.  But there may be some modifications that can rescue it.

It's possible it will be useful to write the quotient rule for derivatives in determinant form: $$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)^\prime = -\det\begin{bmatrix}f/g & g/g\\f^\prime/g & g^\prime/g\\\end{bmatrix}$$

That is correct, unlike my original concept. Is it, however, possible to write the numerator still as a determinant using only the coefficients, assuming perhaps one or more is equal to zero?

Maybe! Note that when you have linear factors ax+b and cx+d, the numerator of the derivative is a constant. But for higher degree polynomials, the numerator of the derivative will be a polynomial that has x's in it -- it won't be a constant. The determinant may need x's as well.
Maybe try a specific example like (ax^2 + bx +c)/(dx^2+ex+f) and see if any interesting pattern happens. (or whichever small degree you want.)

On reflection, one obstacle is the combinatorics: I believe an $n\times n$ determinant has $n!$ terms in it, since it can be expanded as $n$ determinants of $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ matrices.  On the other hand, if you multiply two degree-$n$ polynomials together, you should expect $n^2$ terms.  The mismatch makes me worry about making a determinant agree with a polynomial multiplication.

Perhaps there are only specific degrees of polynomials whose determinant agrees with polynomial multiplication. I found that the only polynomial degrees for which this applies is degree 2^(2k-1)

Can you edit your question to show how you proved the degree 2^(2k-1) statement?
